# When putting an SD/MMC card into SPI mode, can CS go high in between bytes?

Tags: embedded, sd-card, spi

I have a microprocessor with the card's chip select (`CS`) line tied to a 'frame' signal automatically driven by the SPI (SSP) circuit.  This causes `CS` to go high between each byte.

The MMC/SD specs require that `CS` be held low in order to enter SPI mode.  Does it need to be held low the entire time, or only when transmitting each byte of `CMD0`?

Comment: The question is asked clearly but I am afraid it is borderline on-topic for the public here. Good luck...

Comment: @Pascal, then we must become stronger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the sdcard.org site, I found various PDF specifications for SDIO.  None of these seem to have an explicit timing statement which clarifies this.  However, this statement does occur:

> (1) SD Bus mode is selected by CMD0 (Keep Pin 1 to high during CMD0 execution).

from [page 88 of SD Host Controller Simplified Specification Version 2.00](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:fJSi7x6zauYJ:www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/host_controller/simple_spec/Simplified_SD_Host_Controller_Spec.pdf+http://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/host_controller/simple_spec/Simplified_SD_Host_Controller_Spec.pdf&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESidwGEB34-qinV24KRLMfJ7Pp1d-fjRcUPgWA1Ms0U-I2wBBIRHV5I9cYreszNVF14gLADHRiJ7COgjeB9f0LnMi8JO91U5VmQz7lY5Ph8SLDbGHnzsw5MIfOOel2lpBDFD0X5X&sig=AHIEtbT2NFj4EvscFBd2NrZvu33ua_GV2w).  ("Pin 1" is Chip Select (`CS`))

Given that sentence, an SD card manufacturer would be justified in requiring that you assert `CS` through the entire `D0..D15` bits being sent.  In other words, I think you cannot use the SPI frame signal and will need a GPIO pin or similar.

Comment: There is also a GPIO pin - they are combined with an `or` gate.  I guess we'll have to lift a pin to test it.

Comment: Managed to temporarily short out frame; no immediate effect, but I can't rule it out as I try other things.

Comment: Found my other errors (including misconfigured SPI thanks to compiler limitation)  **This card will accept intermediate highs**, but I agree with your analysis in general.

Comment: Very interesting news.  Good job on getting it worked out.  :)